# get data first and then() return widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

very new to dart and firestore ,Trying to make a dynamic Drawer widget . Doing two firebaseDB calls , one to fetch list of say events and another to get venue image of the event from Venue master collection .

Now issue is , the Property remains null the first time , on firing again(closing and opening drawer) returns value ,tried returning within then() (depicted below), but returns nothing as widget expets a widget to be returned,

```
   return ListView.builder(
        reverse: false,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        itemCount: Properties.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {

          Firestore.instance.collection('Properties').document(Properties[i]['PropertyId']).get().then((docSnap) {
            property = docSnap;
            print(property['PropertyImage']);
            if (property==null || !property.exists)
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            else
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Ink.image(
                  image: NetworkImage(property['PropertyImage']),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                ),
              );
          });

        },
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to wrap the ListView in a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). The future should end with `.documents`, and inside the ListView you should use snapshot.data[index] to reference a specific document.

[Here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I) is a good video describing it in more detail.

Edit: If you really need to, the FutureBuilder can be inside the ListView, but that would be very inefficient as it would cause the documents to be fetched one by one instead of all at a time.

Comment: but FutureBuilder needs documents() in future: , I just need a single document with documentID

Comment: Then you need to place the FutureBuilder inside the Listview.builder. that way you can fetch the documents one by one